# How to pass Exceptions array to Attribute

Tags: c#, exception, object, attributes

I am creating Attribute where I need to pass array of Exceptions, how to do that?

Let's say

```
[assembly: MyAttribute(ExceptionList = [System.Web.HttpException, System.Threading.ThreadAbortException]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass exception *types* then you can use `typeof`:

```
[assembly: MyAttribute(ExceptionList = [typeof(System.Web.HttpException), typeof(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException]));
```

If you want to pass exception *objects*, it is not possible. Arguments to attribute constructors can only be constant values (or expressions of a couple of types for which a special exception is made).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list of types rather than Exceptions. This should get you started

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class MyAttribute : Attribute {
    public MyAttribute(Type[] exceptionList) {
    }
}

[MyAttribute(new Type[] { typeof(ArgumentException), typeof(OtherException) } )]
class Test {
    ...
}
```